# Xcode header path for brew downloaded glib-2.0

Tags: xcode, header-files

Some time ago I set up my Xcode C project to link against glib-2.0 installed by Homebrew by adding paths to the Header Search Paths:

[image]

This weekend I pulled the source onto my wife's M-1 Air, brewed up glib again, and now it won't find the headers. I understand Homebrew has moved the default install directories for the M-1 series, so I did `brew link glib-2.0` which responded `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.72.0` and with a bit of poking about from that point I found glib.h in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.72.0/include/glib-2.0/` as well as `/opt/homebrew/include/glib-2.0/`, so I did this:

[image]

But this does not work, Xcode reports `/Users/xxx/Documents/RetroBASIC/src/stdhdr.h:57:10: 'glib.h' file not found`

I don't think I need PATH for this, I believe Xcode settings should be enough right? the glib bin and sbin are in my PATH, just not the include.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, it got so annoying I gave up and wrote the few bits of glib the code was using. It was just GList and GTree.